# assigning class/id names to var

Tags: javascript, html, css, servicenow

This is a follow up question to a previous one I posted.  I've created a table using the following script:

```
<g:evaluate var="jvar_job_details">
var selection = new GlideRecord('u_selection');  
selection.addQuery('u_selection_user.u_candidate_name', gs.getUserID());
selection.query();
var title_list = "<table>";
    title_list += "<tr> <th>" + 'Job Title' + "</th> <th>" + 'Location' + "</th> <th>" + 'Position Number' + "</th> <th>" + 'Certification Number' + "</th> <th>" + 'Grade' + "</th> <th>" + 'Series' + "</th> </tr>";
while(selection.next()) {
    title_list += 
    "<tr> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_job_title.getHTMLValue() +  "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_job_location.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_position_number.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_certification_number.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_grade.getHTMLValue() + "</td> <td>" + selection.u_selection_position_number.u_series.getHTMLValue() + "</td> </tr>";
    }
    title_list +=  "</table>";
</g:evaluate>
```

I was facing some styling issues with CSS, so someone recommended that I give my table a class or id

```
var title_list = "<table class='myClass'>";
```

which fixed the styling problems.  However, my table disappeared.

I'm wondering if my syntax for defining a class name is incorrect.  I've also tried

```
var title_list = $(".myTable");
```

without any success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: `var title_list = "<table class='myClass'>";` should work just fine.

Comment: @Dave take out unnecessary code in the Fiddle man, keep only what relates to the problem

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion my bad, here is the relevant code:  https://jsfiddle.net/yundlu/kj9sqss1/

Answer (score 0):

Try `.addClass`.

```
var title_list = $('table').addClass('class');
```

or if you want to go with plain JavaScript:

```
var title_list = document.getElementsByTagName('table').className = 'class';
```

Although, I don't see what is wrong with:

```
var title_list = "<table class='myClass'>";
```

You should probably check your CSS and see if it is set to `display:none;`, or `visibility:hidden;`